# set up filesharing between windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, file-sharing

I recently purchased a netbook with ubuntu 12.04 lts on it. I am trying to move my files from my windows 7 pc to my netbook but am running into trouble. I have shared my files on my windows pc and have verified it on another windows pc.

There is no homegroup on my windows pc and the workgroup is WORKGROUP, just like on my netbook. However i cannot see my netbook on the network connections. It is on the network with the rest of the computers but it is not visible, nor are the others visible to it.

what do i need to do? i have read through several tutorials that describe how to use samba (which seems to be for sharing files from linux to windows, not the reverse) and several that go through the "Connect to server" menu but i cannot find the connect to server window at all.

Comment: On your netbook, if you click on the launchpad "home folder", do you see the Windows PC under Network/Browse network?  You should see the public folder on the Windows PC at least (and anything else you shared).

Comment: no i see only the linux pc. that i believe is THE problem.

Comment: you can move them through your Ubuntu one account . I did that job before this way : i have installed Ubuntu one program on windows and added my file into it ,then refer the Ubuntu one account on Ubuntu !

Comment: i could. i hesitated in signing up for it when it prompted me at first start up because i dont know too much about it. However, that does not address the issue that i truly want solved. That is a good idea though. It might be of use to point out that this is my first real experience with linux.

Comment: Try installing gvfs.  That might be the piece needed.  Maybe samba-common and samba-client needed too.

Comment: Sometimes the network file system services are working, but the hosts just don't see each other. In that case you can tell Nautilus to access them via IP address by entering `smb://[remote IP address]/` into the address bar. Of course the hosts need to be able to reach eachother (test with `ping [remote IP address]`).